# Using Kamon to generate a TraceContext in Spray

Tags: scala, spray

I am adding Kamon to my spray project. I have added traceName directive and followed the instructions here - http://kamon.io/integrations/logback/trace-token-converter/ Where would one suggest start creating the context via Tracer.withNewContext("simple-test") ?

I had started out using the sbt revolver when I saw some threads related to not starting the context properly ([See here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/kamon-user/v3Uhkrw4hVM/LZgBef11mZUJ)). I would keep seeing the following line:

`a4-dispatcher [WARN] [12/05/2015 10:12:55.967] [Dispatcher-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [SprayExtension(akka://kamon)] EmptyTraceContext present while closing the trace with token [hostname.local-1]`

I stopped using sbt revolver - and now I don't see that line and I see X-Trace-Token in the response header (which is awesome). But, I don't see the token in the logs. The `%token` is still `undefined` as defined in the `LogbackTraceTokenConverter`

Second question: could I be having competing Kamon libraries? I have kamon core, scala, akka, akka-remote, and spray in my build.sbt .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things that need to be in place

- Start Kamon process using AspectJ. See http://kamon.io/introduction/get-started/
- Sbt revolver won't get the tracing information right. It may be because the aspectj weaver doesn't get weaved in the forked JVM.
- Console logging is still not working for me. The closest I could find is this thread - https://groups.google.com/d/msg/kamon-user/uipptjm24gk/OxrbvMw_6EYJ

Comment: My issue was that I was looking only in the console logging and concluded that this was not working. However, the file logging was working as expected.